# If I join The Institute what happens to Nick?

Tags: fallout-4

I met the Institute and I kind of like it, the only thing that i worry about is that if I join I could not interact more with Nick Valentine. Does anything change with Nick if I join the institute?

Comment: Couple of problems here... 1.) You've got two questions. The format for Stack Exchange is one question per post. 2.) The second question is entirely opinion-based, which is not appropriate for SE either. 3.) I presume you meant "good"... In any case, drop the Also bit and this would be a better (and answerable) question.

Answer (score 4):

No, if you join the Institute nothing happens to Nick. He is still available to use as a companion and it doesn't appear to effect his standing with you. It will however open up a few passing comments where he'll query why you're working for them.